# How to make Navigator stay on the active route when StreamProvider updates?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the code below I have created a custom Navigator which is a child to a StreamProvider. My problem is that every time a receive a snapshot from Firestore, the StreamProvider resets the Navigator route. How can I keep the current route while still updating the UI with the new values from the stream?

Also, the ListView in the second code block resets the scroll position on updates from the stream. How can I preserve the scroll position, while still updating the UI with new values?

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Future<void> _onItemTapped(int index) async {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      print(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FixturesPage fixturesPage = new FixturesPage();
    final ProfilePage profilePage = new ProfilePage();

    FirebaseUser user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

    List<Widget> pages = [
      fixturesPage,
      profilePage,
    ];

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<int>.value(
            value: DatabaseService(userId: user.uid).totalPoints),
        StreamProvider<List<Bet>>.value(
            value: BettingService(userId: user.uid).getBetList)
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0, backgroundColor: darkShade5, title: AppBarTitle()),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: darkShade4,
          ),
          child: pages[_selectedIndex],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: darkShade7,
            selectedFontSize: 10,
            unselectedFontSize: 10,
            elevation: 0,
            unselectedIconTheme:
                IconThemeData(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
            selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: mainColor),
            unselectedLabelStyle: navigationBarStyle.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
            selectedLabelStyle: navigationBarStyle.copyWith(color: mainColor),
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage("lib/images/HomeIcon.png"),
                      color: _selectedIndex == 0
                          ? mainColor
                          : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: SizedBox()),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage("lib/images/ProfileIcon.png"),
                      color: _selectedIndex == 1
                          ? mainColor
                          : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: SizedBox()),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: mainColor,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _FixturesPageState extends State<FixturesPage> {
  int selectedTap = 0;

  Function setSelectedTap(int tap) {
    setState(() {
      selectedTap = tap;
    });

    return null;
  }

  Widget selectedSport = FavoritesTap();

  Function setSelectedSport(Widget newSelectedSport) {
    setState(() {
      selectedSport = newSelectedSport;
    });

    return null;
  }

  ScrollController listViewController =
      ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();
    List<dynamic> matches = Provider.of<List<SoccerMatch>>(context);

    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: "/",
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Container(
              color: darkShade6,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //CalendarBar(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      key: PageStorageKey('myListView'),
                      controller: listViewController,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                        LiveSection(eventList: matches),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        UpcomingSection(eventList: matches),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        ResultsSection(eventList: matches)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I fixed both problems by moving the ListView inside its own widget together with the Provider and ScrollController:

```
class _FixturesPageState extends State<FixturesPage> {
  int selectedTap = 0;

  Function setSelectedTap(int tap) {
    setState(() {
      selectedTap = tap;
    });

    return null;
  }

  Widget selectedSport = FavoritesTap();

  Function setSelectedSport(Widget newSelectedSport) {
    setState(() {
      selectedSport = newSelectedSport;
    });

    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: "/",
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Container(
              color: darkShade6,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //CalendarBar(),
                  Expanded(child: FixturesList())
                ],
              )),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FixturesList extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController listViewController =
      ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<dynamic> matches = Provider.of<List<SoccerMatch>>(context);

    return ListView(
      key: PageStorageKey('myListView'),
      controller: listViewController,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 30),
        LiveSection(eventList: matches),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        UpcomingSection(eventList: matches),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        ResultsSection(eventList: matches)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```